# Customize look of window dialog in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

i would like to know if it's possible to change the look of Dialog Window in Applescript, for example change the icon (note, stop, caution) by a custom picture or icon instead.

And if it is possible to change the typography (alignment, font, bold ... etc.)

If yes, could you help me with an example for my code or provided a link to a good tutorial please!

```
set folderName to text returned of (display dialog "Please enter new folder name:" default answer "Folder_Name")
set loc to choose folder "Choose Parent Folder Location"

try
    tell application "Finder"
        set newFolder to make new folder at loc with properties {name:folderName}       
    end tell

    display dialog "Successfully! Want to reveal the new folder?" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Go to my new folder"} default button "Go to my new folder" cancel button "Cancel"
    if button returned of the result = "Go to my new folder" then
        tell application "Finder"
            reveal newFolder
            activate
        end tell
    end if
end try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the typography. However you can use:

```
display dialog "hi" with icon withIconFile
```

where withIconFile is an alias or file reference to a ‘.icns’ file

Answer (score 1):

This is better for me !

```
 display dialog "My custom icon " buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with icon file "Path:to:my.icon.icns"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
display dialog "Hello" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} with icon {"/Users/" & (do shell script "whoami") & "/path/to/picture.jpg"}
```

The `do shell script` part just makes it work, even if you send it to your friends, although I would then recommend downloading the image from the internet with curl and placing it in a folder. Sorry if it is a bit confusing